# Emacs gdb: Show variable permanently in addition to locals i

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am using emacs for programming, and recently also gdb.

The "locals" window does show local variables but not arguments to a function, which in a way also could be considered local variables. For example, if I have

```
void foo(char *bar) 
{
    int n;
    ....
}
```

then `n` is shown in the "locals" but not `bar`. Of course, I can `print bar`  but it is not automatically updated while I step through the code and I have to `print` all the time.

Is there a way to add expressions that are shown in a window and constantly updated as I execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

The [display command](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_56.html) will certainly fulfill your needs:

> If you find that you want to print the value of an expression frequently (to see how it changes), you might want to add it to the
>   automatic display list so that GDB prints its value each time your
>   program stops.

By example, once that your are in foo body (under gdb), type:

```
display bar
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Still, isn't there a possibility to display it in a window, as for example the locals are?

Comment: Yes I understand your request. -> under Emacs I tried the `gdb-display-locals-buffer` command. However, for a reason I ignore, the local vars were not displayed

Answer (score 0):

The interactive command `gud-watch` will watch the expression at point and display its value in the speedbar. Prefix it with `C-u` to be able to enter an expression.

See the manual page `Watch Expressions` for more details.

At the moment there doesn't seem to be a way to display watched expressions in the locals window.